# Gnome Remote Desktop Blank Screen

Tags: gnome

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I am attempting to use the built in Remote Desktop to connect to the computer.

However, I am running into an issue where when I connect the display is black.

I have previously used XRDP but wanted to use this as it will allow me to access the same session as before.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: *Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Just to clarify: both machines are running Ubuntu 22.04.02? And to confirm, for the machine that you're attempting RDP into, no other user is logged in, correct?

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-media-session wireplumber`?

Comment: Another thing: Did you disable and stop xrdp, before enabling GNOME Remote Desktop here? xrdp and GNOME Remote Desktop both use the RDP port 3389 and will fight over it. Only one process can bind to a specific port.